How exactly does graphical-session.target start or get started
The systemd unit file isn't allowed to be run manually so there's gotta be something that triggers it.  Reverse dependencies can call for it but how are they also started?  Normally they  aren't started before startx (or at least they aren't supposed to) so there's gotta be a triggering point.
I'm mostly just interested in how it works with startx, and not with a login manager.
Details on how gnome-session.target works specifically would also be great since it's the most practical example of a session framework implementation that utilizes graphical-session.target.  The gnome-session binary does have a --systemd option.  Perhaps it's where the starting point triggerer is put.  It would be sad to know that binaries can simply bypass RefuseManualStart=yes though.  That would be very... triggering.

In the example of a GNOME session, gnome-session.target requires graphical-session.target.  Specifically, in /usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session.target:
RefuseManualStart=yes
RefuseManualStop=yes

BindsTo=graphical-session.target
Before=graphical-session.target

BindsTo= is similar to Requires=.  "In many cases it is best to combine BindsTo= with After=".  However gnome-session.target does the opposite, for whatever reason.
Grepping further, we find gnome-session-x11@.target:
# Start happens explicitly
RefuseManualStart=no
# Stop happens by starting gnome-session-shutdown.target
#RefuseManualStop=yes

# As this is the main entry point, pull in the other toplevel gnome-session targets

BindsTo=gnome-session.target
After=gnome-session.target

man gnome-session explains "gnome-session  can  pass  much  of  the session management over to systemd", and lists various systemd targets.

gnome-session-x11@SESSION.target / gnome-session-wayland@SESSION.target
Main unit started for X11/wayland based session. SESSION is set according to the session that is passed in --session.


--session=SESSION
Use the applications defined in SESSION.session. If not specified, gnome.session will be used.

gnome-session starts the systemd unit using a StartUnit dbus call, just like systemctl start would.  I don't see it needing (or doing) anything different.  We can confirm the manual start of gnome-session-x11@.target in main.c.
    gnome_session_target = g_strdup_printf ("gnome-session-%s@%s.target", session_type, session_name);

                        if (gsm_util_start_systemd_unit (gnome_session_target, "fail", &error)) {
                                /* We started the unit, open fifo and sleep forever. */
                                systemd_leader_run ();
                                exit (0);
                        }

